# Qt5 move qrc to DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll

In my soluton I want to create second, helper app, which will be using the same resources as my main application. So I want do move all my .qrc files to DLL and use it in both apps on the same time.
I choosed dll format because in future my solution will contain shared functions which I will put in that dll.

How should I compile and attach DLL to use resources in both applications like standard .qrc files?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Which part of the process you need to know more about? I'm sure you know how to build a library with some resources: it's not different from building an application, except that you use `TEMPLATE = lib` instead of `TEMPLATE = app`. I'm also sure you know how to make your project link with a DLL by using the `LIBS += ...` entry. Please clarify exactly what you don't know, and what you've already done. Also note that you might wish to have just one application act as both would, by choosing the variant as a command line argument.

Comment: Ok, I can probably make an DLL correctly, but I don't know How to use resources from that library, and how to use it from designer form

Comment: @km2442 i think you will be not able to use resource from dll in designer. But you will be able to open these files with QFile etc

Answer (score 0):

From the resource or build pointo f view there is no difference.

The `.pro` file of a DLL refers to its resource file exactly the same way as a `.pro` file of an application would.

The libraries resource "tree" can then be "imported" into the application with the `QT_INIT_RESOURCE` macro, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library

Comment: Could you provide an example of DLL with only .qrc and application which uses resources from DLL? I can't make resources visible in app resource tree :(